# How to perform simple string operations in snakemake output

Tags: python, snakemake

I am creating my first snakemake file, and I got to the point where I need to perform a simple string operation on the value of my `output`, so that my `shell` command works as expected:

```
rule sketch:
  input:
    'out/genomes.txt'
  output:
    'out/genomes.msh'
  shell:
    'mash sketch -l {input} -k 31 -s 100000 -o {output}'
```

I need to apply the `split` function to `{output}` so that only the name of the file up to the extension is used. I couldn't find anything in the docs or in related questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could remove the extension within the shell command

```
rule sketch:
  input:
    'out/genomes.txt'
  output:
    'out/genomes.msh'
  shell:
    'mash sketch -l {input} -k 31 -s 100000 -o $(echo "{output}" | sed -e "s/.msh//")'
```

Comment: This is so far the most elegant solution, although it should be possible in principle to perform very basic operations on input/output. Sad!

Answer (score 4):

You could use the params field:

```
rule sketch:
  input:
    'out/genomes.txt'
  output:
    'out/genomes.msh'
  params:
    dir = 'out/genomes'
  shell:
    'mash sketch -l {input} -k 31 -s 100000 -o {params.dir}'
```

Answer (score 4):

Best is to use `params`:

```
rule sketch:
    input:
        'out/genomes.txt'
    output:
        'out/genomes.msh'
    params:
        prefix=lambda wildcards, output: os.path.splitext(output[0])[0]
    shell:
        'mash sketch -l {input} -k 31 -s 100000 -o {params.prefix}'
```

It is always preferable to use `params` instead of using the `run` directive, because the `run` directive cannot be combined with conda environments.

Answer (score 3):

Alternative solution using wildcards:

```
rule all:
  input: 'out/genomes.msh'

rule sketch:
  input:
    '{file}.txt'
  output:
    '{file}.msh'
  shell:
    'mash sketch -l {input} -k 31 -s 100000 -o {wildcards.file}'
```

Untested, but I think this should work.

The advantage over the `params` solution is that it generalizes better.

Answer (score 2):

Avoid duplicating text. Don't use params unless you convert your input/outputs to wildcards + extentions. Otherwise you're left with a rule that is hard to maintain.

```
input:
    "{pathDIR}/{genome}.txt"
output:
    "{pathDIR}/{genome}.msh"
params:
    dir: '{pathDIR}/{genome}'
```

Otherwise, [use Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-slice-notation).

I couldn't seem to get slice notation to work in the params using the output wildcard. Here it is in the run directive.

```
from subprocess import call

rule sketch:
  input:
    'out/genomes.txt'
  output:
    'out/genomes.msh'
  run:
    callString="mash sketch -l " + str(input) + " -k 31 -s 100000 -o " + str(output)[:-4]
    print(callString)
    call(callString, shell=True)
```

Python underlies Snakemake. I prefer the "run" directive over the "shell" directive because I find it really unlocks a lot of that beautiful Python functionality. The accessing of params and various things are slightly different that with the "shell" directive.

E.g.

```
callString=config["mpileup_samtoolsProg"] + ' view -bh -F ' + str(config["bitFlag"]) + ' ' + str(input.inputBAM) + ' ' + wildcards.chrB2M[1:]
```

[A bit of a snippet of J.K. using the run directive.](http://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/latest/project_info/faq.html?highlight=run%20directive#can-the-output-of-a-rule-be-a-symlink)

[All of the rules in my modules pretty much use the run directive](https://github.com/tboyarski/BCCRC-Snakemake/tree/master/modules)